# SQL | Use a Inner Join to combine to tables where the last day of month is different

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm having a bit of trouble here combining data from two tables (via a join) because one table is using the last day of the month whereas the other is using the last working day of the month.

How can I do this? I was thinking about using the last day available of each month but I'm unsure how to do that.

```
**LEFT JOIN Database.SIT_DAILLY SIT 
    ON A.NUC=SIT.NUC
    AND A.DAY=SIT.DAY

WHERE A.DAY = '2022-04-30'**
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: assuming that the last working day of the month is within the month (because some companies will be very odd about how they label such things), you should be able to use the LAST_DAY() function: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Functions-Operators-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2017/DateTime-and-Interval-Functions-and-Expressions/LAST_DAY

Comment: Ignoring the day: each table also has a unique key on the month of that date. Therefore you can JOIN on the month, e.g., `YEAR(A.DAY) = YEAR(SIT.DAY) AND MONTH(A.DAY) = MONTH(SIT.DAY)`.

Comment: Agree - join on YYYYMM forget about picking a day. If you have to pick a day make both of them the first of the month as that's easy to work out and every month has one

Comment: When you do a calculation on a column you will loose statistics, extracting year/month on both columns is worst case. If one column is the last day of a month already applying LAST_DAY on the other column is the way to go.